# Querying list of domains available , Environment is having multiple NIC cards for two different domains

Tags: c#, .net, ldap, directoryentry

I am using LDAP for querying the list of domains available. My logic works fine when i run this on a machine where one nic card is available and it is successfully querying the list of domains, However when i run this on a machine which is having multiple nic cards i.e. One for Domain A and other one for Domain B, I am getting exception reason is simple i.e. DirectoryEntry() binding is failing.

***I need to use LDAP provider only for this.***

Below is the code snippet :

```
using (DirectoryEntry RootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE"))
    {
        // Retrieve the Configuration Naming Context from RootDSE
        string configNC = RootDSE.Properties["configurationNamingContext"].Value.ToString();

        // Connect to the Configuration Naming Context
        using (DirectoryEntry configSearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + configNC))
        {
            // Search for all partitions where the NetBIOSName is set.
            using (DirectorySearcher configSearch = new DirectorySearcher(configSearchRoot))
            {
                configSearch.Filter = ("(NETBIOSName=*)");

                // Configure search to return dnsroot and ncname attributes
                configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnsroot");
                configSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("ncname");
                using (SearchResultCollection forestPartitionList = configSearch.FindAll())
                {
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an LDAP binding string without a server or domain, like `LDAP://rootDSE`, the default domain will be the domain that the computer is joined to.  If the computer isn't joined to a domain, then the binding will fail (you would also need to provide a username and password).  The user running the app, or the thread for web sites/services, or the user if one was specified during binding, must be able to read on the target domain, otherwise the binding will fail.

If none of this fixes your problem, then you need to give more information about the two domains.  For example, are they in the same forest?